# How can an antisymmetric relation be not reflexive?

Tags: relations

Reading a book (I do not know if I can mention its title) I found these definition (the following is exactly the quotation from the pages of the book):
"For a binary relation R on a set Y, that is, R⊆YxY, it is customary to write xRy rather than (x,y)∈R.
A binary relation R on a set X is: - reflexive if xRx; - antisymmetric if xRy and yRx imply x=y. An antisymmetric relation may or may not be reflexive"
I do not get how an antisymmetric relation could not be reflexive. Can you explain it conceptually? A concrete example aside the theory would be appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: Let $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ and $R=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$. Is $R$ reflexive?

Comment: The empty relation on any non empty set is an example.

Comment: A strict inequality is an example of such a relation; $xRy$ if and only if $x < y$. It's vacuously antisymmetric as there are no $x, y$ with $x < y$ and $y < x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I guess no since (3,3) does not belongs to R. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for antisymmetry only says that *if* $xRy$ and $yRx$ are both true, then $x=y$. Put differently, it says that if $x \neq y$, then it's impossible for both $xRy$ and $yRx$ to be true. This doesn't say anything about whether $xRx$ is true or false for some or all $x$.

Conceptually, think of antisymmetry as ensuring that two distinct elements cannot both be $R$ to each other, but it is completely indifferent to whether or not an element is $R$ with itself.

(By the way "reflexive" means that $xRx$ holds for *all* $x$ in the set. The quote in the question leaves the variable $x$ unquantified in that definition, which is a serious error.)

The relations $<$ and $\leq$ on natural numbers are both antisymmetric, but only the second one is reflexive: **Every** number $n$ satisfies $n \leq n$, but **no** number satisfies $n < n$. Antisymmetry holds for both of them because for two **distinct** numbers $m,n$, only one of $m \leq n$ and $n \leq m$ can be true, and also only one of $m < n$ and $n < m$.

Comment: I did not mention it but previously in the book it is specified that the quantifiers "for every..." are understood as written, sorry about that. Now I am thinking about your answers to see whether I get the concept

Comment: Ok your examples are great. However, now I am afraid of misunderstanding something "bigger"? If I say that both $xRy$ and $yRx$ are true, then $x=y$, it comes natural to me to substitute $y$ with $x$, and to say that $xRx$ is true too. Clearly this is wrong in the light of what said right now. What is exactly wrong? Where am I overflowing whit this deduction?

Comment: You are welcome to substitute x for y, but what do you get in the condition of anti symmetry when you do that? You get: if xRx and xRx are true, then xRx. This is very different from saying "xRx is true for all x".

Comment: So, I get nothing but a tautology. Am I correct? In particular, this would be true just for the lets say "reflexive" $x$s (since my hypothesis is exactly $xRx$), but nothing can be said about a generic $x$. Right?

Comment: The condition "if xRX then xRX" holds always, as you said. It doesn't hold just for those x's for which xRx; it holds for all x's. Make sure you understand why. ("If m is even then m is divisible by 2" is a statement that holds for m=3, too).

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot get what you mean with this "The condition "if xRX then xRX" holds always, as you said. It doesn't hold just for those x's for which xRx; it holds for all x's". However, I think I properly get the idea.